# Ordering questions by most recently answered and filtering those unanswered by a particular user

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm having trouble writing an Active Record query that returns the results I want. I have the following setup:

abridged `User` model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :answers
end
```

abridged `Answer` model:

```
class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :question
  belongs_to :user
end
```

abridged `Question` model:

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :answers

  def self.unanswered_by(user)
    where(
      'id NOT IN (SELECT question_id FROM answers WHERE user_id = ?)',
      user.id
    )
  end

  def self.recently_answered
    includes(:answers).order('answers.updated_at DESC')
  end
end
```

I'm trying to get an `ActiveRecord::Relation` back that orders the questions by those that have been most recently answered and then filters that result so it only contains questions a `current_user` has yet to answer.

Ideally, I'd like to write

```
Question.recently_answered.unanswered_by current_user
```

but this doesn't appear to work and I'm struggling to understand why with my limited understanding of SQL.

This is the result I get when I run this in the Rails console:

```
me = User.find(8)
Question.recently_answered.unanswered_by me
=>   SQL (0.5ms)  SELECT `questions`.`id` AS t0_r0,
     `questions`.`question_text` AS t0_r1,
     `questions`.`example_answer` AS t0_r2,
     `questions`.`created_at` AS t0_r3,
     `questions`.`updated_at` AS t0_r4,
     `answers`.`id` AS t1_r0,
     `answers`.`question_id` AS t1_r1,
     `answers`.`user_id` AS t1_r2,
     `answers`.`answer_text` AS t1_r3,
     `answers`.`created_at` AS t1_r4,
     `answers`.`updated_at` AS t1_r5
     FROM `questions` LEFT OUTER JOIN `answers`
     ON `answers`.`question_id` = `questions`.`id`
     WHERE (id NOT IN (SELECT question_id FROM answers WHERE user_id = 8))
     ORDER BY answers.updated_at DESC
     #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x3fd42e362a80>
```

Running `Question.recently_answered.unanswered_by(me).to_sql` gives me this:

```
=> "SELECT `questions`.*
   FROM `questions`
   WHERE (id NOT IN (SELECT question_id
          FROM answers WHERE user_id = 8))
   ORDER BY answers.updated_at DESC"
```

I'm working around this right now by doing

```
Question
  .recently_answered
  .reject { |q| q.answers.map(&:user_id).include? current_user.id }
```

but this returns an `Array` of `Question` objects instead of the `ActiveRecord::Relation` that I'd prefer.

Could someone help me understand why I can't chain `recently_answered` and `unanswered_by` as written and how I could go about rewriting this so I can get the result I want? Thanks.

Comment: in the `unanswered_by` method's implementation, the `id` column might be ambiguous (if you do joins). Use the table's name before `id` to make sure there is no ambiguous call to the `id` column (use `questions.id NOT IN ...`)

Comment: Also, these methods should be defined as `scope` (in your case: `scope :recently_answered, -> { includes(:answers).order('interview_answers.updated_at DESC') }`)

Comment: @MrYoshiji Thanks. It makes a lot of sense now that you pointed out `id` is ambiguous in the `unanswered_by` method. It appears it works when I do `questions.id NOT IN ...` as you suggest. Good call on using scopes instead of class methods here. I'll rewrite them. Add as an answer I'll gladly accept. Thanks again for helping me understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add the table's name in the SQL query of the `unanswered_by` method:

```
  def self.unanswered_by(user)
    where('questions.id NOT IN (SELECT question_id FROM answers WHERE user_id = ?)', user.id)
          #^^^^^^^^^ table's name added here
  end
```

Because if you use this combined with a `joins`/`includes`, your DB adapter will not know from which table you select the id (error message like `column id is ambiguous`).

Also, you should probably use `scope` instead for these 2 methods.